# serialize + dato en ajax

Tags: php, ajax

estoy tratando de de adjuntar un dato a un serialize, si funciona debe imprimir un texto con las variables enviadas en el div "resp".

```
<?php
 $mes = "marzo";
?>
<script>
var tiempo = "llueve";
$(document).on('ready',function(){

  $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
    var url = "datos.php";                                      

    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: $("#formulario").serialize() + "&tiempo=" + tiempo,
       success: function(data)            
       {
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  });
});
</script>

<form method="post" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
    <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mes" value="<?php echo $mes; ?>">
    <input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />
</form>
<div id="resp"></div>
```

datos.php

```
<?php   
 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $contraseña  = $_POST['contrasena'];
 $mes  = $_POST['mes'];
 $tiempo  = $_POST['tiempo'];
echo "tu usuario es: ".$usuario." contraseña es: ".$contraseña." y el mes es ".$mes" ,tambien ".$tiempo; 
?>
```

Comment: Que error te genera?

Comment: no muestra nada el div en pantalla cuando hago click en en ingresar

Comment: Prueba quitando los espacios, en ocaciones dan problemas

Comment: Quitando los espacios sigue sin imprimir en pantalla.

Comment: pon un console.log(data); debajo de tu succes antes de tus llaves, y dime que te trae?

Comment: post con error 500

Comment: la variable tiempo en que parte de tu html esta?

Comment: la declare en el script